# How to make selecting a timezone more user-friendly?

Tags: java, user-interface, coldfusion, timezone, user-experience

The [list of timezones](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) is rather long, lots of duplication, and not very friendly to programmers let alone end-users.

Is there a way to to shorten the list to something friendlier and sufficient for 80%+ of users?  But then how shall one decide which are the *popular* Tz?

The list in Windows seems pretty good, but I'm not sure if that's a good list to model after.  It is interesting because DST is optional, is that why the list can be that short?  Someone [worked out the tz equivalents here](http://www.aviblock.com/blog/2009/03/12/presenting-a-list-of-timezones-to-the-user/).

I'm in Pacific Daylight Time (PDT). JS's `getTimezoneOffset()` returns 420 ==> offset -7.  If I use the timezones list above, how would one tell it's US/Pacific (-8)?

Furthermore, what are the popular names for timezones?  `US/Pacific` or `Canada/Pacific` sure sounds friendlier then `America/Los_Angeles` or `America/Vancouver`.

Lastly, how are the 2 timezones above different?  Can they be safely grouped together and just use `America/Los_Angeles` in the app?  How shall one group timezones together?

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to ask this on the UX stack ;)

Comment: *"Is there a way to to shorten the list"*  Live on a smaller planet?  Wipe out half the exiting planet?  Use decimal time?  ..

Comment: Why are those timezones different? In the past they probably had different daylight savings time rules. If you're dealing with historical dates, the distinction might matter!

Comment: @JasonMalinowski what if I don't care about historical date for my app?  Is there a way to merge them as long as they are the same in the foreseeable future?

Comment: @vzwick http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21409/how-to-make-selecting-a-timezone-more-user-friendly

Comment: As long as your source of timezone information lets you figure out the current DST transitions, you could merge if they are equivalent. That of course gets back to your original question of which is the best name. @azawaza's answer of there is no answer seems best.

Comment: Well, how do you guys think about how Windows group the available timezones?  Do you think that's a good model to follow?

Answer (score 2):

Friendly TZ names are subjective - one likes one name while someone else gets offended by it.
Instead of trying to figure out how to shorten the tz list, why don't you implement geolocation and pre-select users' timezone for them?

It is not 100% accurate, and for travelling folk is just wrong, but that's better than make your users scroll through an endless list, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this approach](http://timezonepicker.com/) it seams very friendly to me and well documented on how to do it.

Comment: "Link only" answers are discouraged because they become meaningless if the link breaks or changes.  Consider updating your answer to include a brief summary of the approach you are recommending. Then it will remain useful in the future, even without the link.